# Contract Deployment on mumbai testnet stuck at (pending)

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, testnets, polygon

Im running through some tutorials and all the contracts that I deploy to the polygon testnet always get stuck sitting there as (Pending). Any ideas why that would be?

Here's an example of one:

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xeef7926de6c57ff89599183a4101501190a9e7bad4b6f9755560062bb00199b3

Comment: This has been happening to me too. Try first deploying to a local blockchain, like Hardhat network, Ganache, or the Remix local network first and test what you can, make sure it deploys correctly. Then if you need to test on a live testnet, you can try cancelling the transaction and retrying with higher gas, I literally just did this. There also may be a way to fork the polygon testnet with hardhat.

Comment: How much gas (wei) are you setting?

Comment: I'm just setting gas to high from metamask client. Tried setting it manually to 50 but it was fighting me. Last deployment I did 1 hr ago was 36 gwei

Comment: Silly question, but where in the metamask client can you set the gas? I'm sending my transactions via the private key and hardhat so I thought we'd just specify the gas on the deploy of the contract. Also, with the pending transactions Im not seeing them in my metamask wallet activity so I can't cancel or speed them up, not sure if im missing something

Comment: The only silly question is the one you don't ask. When Metamask pops up with the confirm button, there should be a button to edit the gas price, priority fee, and gas limit. You can also edit them in your hardhat deploy script with ethers, like `factory.deploy(1, 1, 2, 1, { gasLimit: 500000 , gasPrice: 50000000000})`. Full documentation here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/transactions/

Comment: Cheers for your help mate. It just looks like they were all really delayed. Overnight they got processed. Not sure whether that's to be expected with the testnet